# Dockerfile creation and building image

Tags: boot2docker, dockerfile

I am new to docker. I have installed docker using Boot2docker on my windows. But I do not have clear idea how to deploy simple java web app in docker.

I have gone through the net and came to know that from docker file create build an image and run it.

I created one `dockerfile` and placed in `D:\dock` folder. 
I ran  `docker build` command like this i.e
`$ docker build -t tomcat7-test Dockerfile's path.`

But it did not recognize my file.

Where should be my `Dockerfile` should exist if I create through `notepad++` and how docker recognize my docker file with docker build command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Dockerfile should be copied into boot2docker VM in order to run it.
You can do one of the following:

1. create Dockerfile in boot2docker manually (note: filesystem is read-only, you should do 'sudo -s' before running docker build, or
2. mount a folder from your local filesystem
3. use

How to add shared folder into boot2docker VM:

```
VBoxManage.exe sharedfolder add boot2docker-vm --name /c/Users --hostpath C:/Users --automount
```

By using option 2 you can edit Dockerfile from your home directory and run docker on the same Dockerfile (replace the example with a real path to Dockerfile):

```
docker build -t myimage /c/Users/xyz
```